# Remove elements from DB that are not in an array, adding elements from an array that are not in DB

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, django, python-3.x

I'm currently trying to create a `view` in Django to receive and process `JSON` data from a `POST request`. I'm currently having issues trying to add/update multiple `NotificationEmail` objects in my database.

What I would like to do is to check if the emails inside the array (`email`) sent via the `POST`  request are already stored in a `NoticationEmail`  object as the `emailAddress` element for that object. If it already exists as the `emailAddress`  for a `NotificationEmail`  object, I would like to keep it. If the email inside the array is not stored in any `NotificationEmail`  object as the `emailAddress`  value, I would like to add a new `NotificationEmail`  object with this email as the `emailAddress`  value. And finally, if there's any `NotificationEmail`  for that specific `id` (given through the POST request) with an  `emailAddress`  value that is not listed in the `emails array` I want to delete it.

I'm currently just getting an error message for the `for`  loops I've created, so I can't run the server and try it out. I've checked that without the `for`  loops it does receive the `POST`  request and is able to add the full `array`  of emails as an `emailAddress`  value inside an `NotificationEmail`  object for that `id` . But this is not the behavior I would like to have in my program.

My code for the `Django view`  is the following:

```
@csrf_exempt
def editMachines(request):
       if request.method == 'POST':
                json_data = json.loads(request.body)
                a = Machine.objects.filter(id = json_data['id']).update(name = json_data['machine_name'])
                userid = a.user_id
                b = NotificationEmail.objects.filter(machine_id = json_data['id'].values()
                for i in range (len(json_data['email'])):
                        exists = false
                        count = 0
                        while exists == false or count < len(b):
                                if json_data['email'][i] == b[count]['emailAddress']:
                                        exists = true
                                        count++
                                else:
                                        b[count].delete()
                                        d = NotificationEmail(machine_id = json_data['id'], email = json_data['email'][i].values(), user = userid)
                                        d.save()
                                        count++



                return HttpResponse(status = 200)
```

And this is the `JavaScript` code that sends the `POST request`:

```
 function updateMachine(){
                            var e = $('#emailAdd').val()
                            var emails = e.split(', ')
                            console.log(emails);
                            var data = {id : machineid, machine_name : $('#name').val(), email : emails};
                                    console.log(data)
                                    $.ajax({
                                            type:'POST',
                                            url:'/edit/machines/', 
                                            data: JSON.stringify(data),
                                            dataType: 'json',
                                            contentType: 'application/json',
                                            statusCode : {
                                                    200 : function(){
                                                                      alert("User updated.");
                                                                        window.location = "/users/dashboard/";
                                                    }
                                            },
                                            async : false
                                    });
                             }
```

I know the `Ajax` in `Javascript` is working fine since I was able to do some changes with it, but I'm having a lot of troubles trying to get the `Django view` to do what I need.

I would highly appreciate if anyone can guide me on what I can do to achieve it. :(

Thanks in advance!

Comment: seems like you are missing right round brace in this line  b = NotificationEmail.objects.filter(machine_id = json_data['id'].values()